# Trouble on installing, getopt file missing

Tags: installation, compiling

total noob here, but my work requires me working on ubuntu. I'm trying to install a program, but this is what's popping up.

```
$sudo perl Makefile.PL
Warning: prerequisite Getopt::ArgvFile 1.11 not found.
Warning: prerequisite XML::DOM 1.44 not found.
Writing Makefile for umph
Writing MYMETA.yml
$
```

Having a little trouble understanding the "INSTALL" file as well. It just lists this:

## PREREQUISITES

### Required

- Perl 5.10.1+
- Getopt::ArgvFile
- XML::DOM

### Recommended

- Umph::Prompt
  for --interactive

### Additionally, to install:

- ExtUtils::MakeMaker

## INSTALLATION

### Notes

Uninstall earlier versions of umph if you have any installed.

### Typical installation

To install:

```
  perl Makefile.PL
  make
  make install
```

- Note that you can specify install prefix with INSTALL_BASE
  e.g. perl Makefile.PL INSTALL_BASE=/usr/local

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: What program are you installing?

Comment: this is https://github.com/BlakeDickie/umph

Answer (score 1):

While `Getopt` is the part of perl core, `Getopt::ArgvFile` is not. You should install `Getopt::ArgvFile` separately.

Run

```
sudo apt install libgetopt-argvfile-perl
```

Answer (score 0):

This

```
sudo perl Makefile.PL
Warning: prerequisite Getopt::ArgvFile 1.11 not found.
```

is related to this:

```
Required

    Getopt::ArgvFile
```

You need to install Getopt 1st (and all of its dependencies).

The weird thing... Getopt belongs to the core utils.

Check if this works:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl  
use Getopt::Std;
```

save it as `filename.pl` and do

```
perl -wc filename.pl
```

It should not error out. If is does check where Getopts is installed or you can add Getopt like this:

```
perl -e shell -MCPAN
cpan>install Getopt::Std
```

Finaly I would try to file a bug or leave a comment for the creator or maintainer of that program.